# Object detection framework with SGDClassifier

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, object-detection

I'm trying to implement standart framework [HOG + LinearSVM [dalal,triggs,2005]](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) using [SGDClassifier from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html).

I'm trying to imitate ['hard negatives mining'](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/2011/results/proj4/psastras/) procedure by online iterative learning using partial_fit method of SGDClassifier.
I compute new N random negative samples and have same N positive samples for each iteration.(So I have N positives and N negatives = balanced dataset)

I define classifer like this:

```
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(shuffle=True, n_iter= 1,verbose=1)
```

and output is something like this:

```
iter1:
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 27.85, NNZs: 144, Bias: -0.065013, T: 50, Avg. loss: 1.754196
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.

iter2:
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 39.46, NNZs: 144, Bias: -0.117644, T: 50, Avg. loss: 0.282976
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.

iter3:
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 37.74, NNZs: 144, Bias: -0.117644, T: 50, Avg. loss: 0.000000
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.

iter4:
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 36.17, NNZs: 144, Bias: -0.117644, T: 50, Avg. loss: 0.000000
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
```

When classifer reaches loss= 0.0 all samples classified as negatives, what does loss=0.0 mean and what I'm doing wrong?